# how to add confirm box before submit buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

**adding confirm box**

Here is my code and I want to add a confirmation box to it.

I have a form with two `submit` buttons. I need the confirmation box with them and then send to the next page. How can I do this?
        this is the code for confirmation box,how can i place it in my form ?

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"
```

myform.jsp

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="center">Enter your choice:-
    <label> <br />
    <label>
       <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="delete" onclick="this.form.action='logi.jsp?flag=1&act=1';this.form.submit();" />
    </label>
    <br />
    </br>
    <label>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Delete" onclick="this.form.action='delete1.jsp?flag=1&act=1';this.form.submit();" />
    </label>
    <br/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On button class try this

```
$('.class').appendTo('body')
  .html('<div><h6>Yes or No?</h6></div>')
  .dialog({
  modal: true, title: 'message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
  width: 'auto', resizable: false,
  buttons: {
      Yes: function () {
          doFunctionForYes();
          $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      No: function () {
          doFunctionForNo();
          $(this).dialog("close");
      }
  },
  close: function (event, ui) {
      $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/your/url.xyz" onsubmit="return confirm('bla bla');">
```

Comment: where to give the second button action??

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Delete" onclick='confirm(this,"delete1.jsp?flag=1&act=1")' />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="delete" onclick='confirm(this,"logi.jsp?flag=1&act=1")' />

function confirm(this,foo1)
{
var foo = confirm('Are you sure?');
if (foo) {this.form.action=foo1;this.form.submit();}
else {alert('Try Later');}
}
```

Comment: Following code is passing image and text field. After the post request in the display.jsp the text field value is null if enctype="multipart/form-data" and image is displayed. If enctype is not used it gives the correct value of textfield and no image is displayed. Can we get both image and text from the same page in JSP?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet is the solution. You need to remove `this.form.submit()` as the buttons are submit buttons and by default they submit.

Just add `onsubmit=" return window.confirm('Are you sure?');"` to the form and remove `this.form.submit()` from submit buttons.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit=" return window.confirm('Are you sure?');">
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                        <p align="center">Enter your choice:-
                            <label> <br />


         <label>
           <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="delete" onclick="this.form.action='logi.jsp?flag=1&act=1';" />
            </label>
                                <br />

                            </br>
                   <label>
                 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Delete" onclick="this.form.action='delete1.jsp?flag=1&act=1';" />
           </label>
                                <br/>

                        </div></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
See this code confirm box works in this way and one sugesstion your code need a lot pf improvement

<html>
<head>
<script>
function disp_confirm()
{
var r=confirm("Press a button!")
if (r==true)
  {
  alert("You pressed OK!")
  }
else
  {
  alert("You pressed Cancel!")
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="disp_confirm()" value="Display a confirm box">

</body>
</html>
```